# ToString() function adding a zero in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, biginteger

Whenever I use the BigInteger.ToString("X") method to "convert" a BigInteger value to HEX, it adds an additional zero for some obscure reason (to me). For instance:

```
Dim val As New BigInteger
Dim res As New String

val = 604462909807314587353089

res = val.ToString("X")
```

In this case, res equals:

```
res: 080000000000000000001
```

This first zero is bothering, as I am passing these values down to some device which only allows a certain number of HEX characters. I could of course easily remove it with an additional line or two, but given my program is also a huge parsing loop, I am afraid doing so will lengthen the execution time.

Any idea where does this come from?
Thank you very much. :)

Comment: just try this: `res = val.ToString("X").Remove(0,1)`

Comment: @Mederic: more readable imo: `val.ToString("X").Substring(1)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter true! but careful you forgot `v` for `val`

Comment: Not only *this* number. It seems that most-significant digits greater than 7 are always prepended by 0, eg 2048 becomes `0800`, `524288` becomes `080000`. That doesn't happen with the equivalent `int` values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading 0 shows you that the number is positive. In signed integer, the largest bit is used as a sign bit, therefore it represents negative number.

For example:

```
// Sorry this is in C#
// 0x00 ~ 0x7F is always positive (0~127), no need to add leading 0
// 0x80 ~ 0xFF in signed number would be negative(-128~-1), but in unsigned it will be 128~255
new BigInteger(128).ToString("X") == "080"; // this is positive 128!
new BigInteger(-128).ToString("X") == "80"; // this is negative 128!
```

Notice that the leading 0 helped you to determine what number it is actually.

If you know how many digits you will be passing to other device, then I would recommend to actually truncate/ format it to specific digits, by for ex: ToString("X20") will always format to 20 digits.
The leading 0 should affect almost none in your calculation, so you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: It would be great if you had a reference to that. This isn't mentioned in the documentation of `BigInteger.ToString()`. longs and ints for example, don't work this way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It definitely makes sense, but I find it quite weird that this behavior only is for BigInteger values.

Comment: By the way, the ToString("X20") trick does not work. The added zero bypasses even the NumberFormatInfo.

Comment: Then please follow what @TimSchmelter suggested or if you'd like to always have 20 digits with leading zeroes `.PadLeft(21,'0').Substring(1,20);`